# ZF2 Custom query

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello and good morning to you all,

I am following the qickstart tutorial from Rob Allen in the manual.
I am trying to change some things. One of the things I am trying to do is to get a query like this:

```
"SELECT max(id) FROM Albums";
```

I tried things like

```
$this->select();
$this->columns(array('id' => 'MAX(id)'));
```

Apparently this is not the way to do it. 
I probablly need some expression object or so.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

### EDIT (forget the above)

This whole code is based on the quickstart in the manual (ZF2)
I have managed to write a query like this:

```
    $select = $this->getSql()->select();
    $select->columns(array(new Expression('max(id) as MaxId')));
    $rowset = $this->selectWith($select);
    $row = $rowset->current();
    return $row;
```

The result of this is an empty object.

But when i change

```
    $select->columns(array(new Expression('max(id) as MaxId')));
```

to

```
  $select->columns(array(new Expression('max(id) as id')));
```

then i get back an object with the id as 1. Which is the max(id).

But when I add in my album object in the function exchangeArray one line with maxId, then it returns the maxId field.

BUT, it can't be that i need to do this everytime i just want to do a query like this. Is this really the way it works?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Zend\Db\Sql\Expression](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Expression.html)

So if i see this correctly (which may not be the case) you'd do it like you just did, but wrap the SQL-Expression into `new Expression('max(id))`. So it should be like the following

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
//...
$this->columns(array(
    'maxid' => new Expression('max(id)')
));
```

If the syntax like this is wrong, please don't curse me, but i would assume that knowing about the Sql\Expression will already help you ;)