# ZF2 table getaway select with IF() in columns

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, zend-framework2

I want to get the following type of query with ZF2 using its tableGateway.

```
SELECT IF(column1 LIKE 'text', 1, 0)
FROM table
WHERE (column1 LIKE 'text' OR column2 LIKE 'text') AND status = 1
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I have tries the following:

```
$this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($keyword) {

    $select->columns(array('id', "IF(column1 LIKE '{$keyword}', 1, 0)"), false)
           ->where(array(
                    new Predicate(
                        array(
                             new Like('column1', '%'.$keyword.'%'),
                             new Like('column2', '%'.$keyword.'%')

                         ),
                         Predicate::COMBINED_BY_OR
                    ),
                 'status' => 1
            ));
        });
```

But this gives the error saying `Unknown column 'IF(column1 LIKE 'test', 1, 0)' in 'field list'`.
Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

When I var_dump-ed the sql String, I got the following:

```
SELECT `id` AS `id`, `IF(table.column1 LIKE 'test', 1, 0)` AS `IF(table.column1 LIKE 'test', 1, 0)` 
FROM `table`
WHERE (`table`.`column1` LIKE '%test%' OR `table`.`column2` LIKE '%test%') 
      AND `table`.`status` = '1';
```

So it places my IF in **`** quotes and treats it like column. So the question is how to disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550490/zf2-custom-query) I figured it out. Just need to put the IF statement in `Expression`, like this:

```
$select->columns(array('id',  new Expression("IF(column1 LIKE '{$keyword}', 1, 0)")), false)
```